# my css3 animation not working on iphone safari

Tags: css, text, css-animations, mobile-safari

below is the codepen for the same:
https://codepen.io/bini-ved/pen/gZzjzX

My css3 animation not working on iphone safari.

```
<div class="bb">
  <h4>3 March 2019</h4> 
  <h5>hello World</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw it working on iphone7 See this url : http://www.responsinator.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io%2Fbini-ved%2Ffull%2FgZzjzX

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `clip: rect(0,0,0,0);` to your `.bb::before, .bb::after` style. It's working fine when you include it.

You can test it [here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/MZGReY).

Comment: Please accept the answer if it fixes your problem. So it can help others.! thanks